# Regular expressions capture text between 3 but not 4 repeating characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that would capture text between repeating characters. I want to capture text only between 3 repeating characters but I don't want to match text between 4 or more characters.

Example:

```
==Text not to capture==
===Text to capture===
====Text not to capture====
=====Text not to capture=====
```

This regex would capture those with 3 === and more:

```
(?<=[=]{3})(.*?)(?=[=]{3})
```

How do I exclude those with 4 or more characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add negative look-arounds to your code to ensure there isn't another `=` before/after the part you're capturing.

```
(?<=(?<![=])[=]{3})(?![=])(.*?)(?<![=])(?=[=]{3}(?![=]))
```

If you want to see that broken down:

The first look-behind ensures your code is preceded by `===`. The negative look-behind inside ensures that *that* isn't preceded by *another* `=`. Then the look-ahead ensures it's not followed by another `=`.

```
(?<=(?<![=])[=]{3})(?![=])
```

Capture some stuff, which can include `=` characters:

```
(.*?)
```

And then make sure you have `===`, again with a nested look-around to ensure there isn't another `=` on the outside, and a separate (smaller) look-around to ensure there isn't another one on the inside.

```
(?<![=])(?=[=]{3}(?![=]))
```

Comment: Almost, but it still captures `=something=` inside `====something====`. Add more lookaround.

Comment: Fixed that problem, bearing in mind that it looks awful and I'm pretty sure it's not fixed _well_. Still thinking on improvements.

Comment: This one worked for me. It captured only === and capturing group has needed text. Thank you!

Comment: This only work with Ruby 2.0 and causes error in Ruby 1.9.3 due to the nested negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, and take the capturing group:

```
(?<!=)={3}([^=]+)={3}(?!=)
```

or if you want to allow `=` inside:

```
(?<!=)={3}((?>[^=]+|=(?!==(?:[^=]|$)))+)={3}(?!=)
```

Comment: Nice. Michelle's solution, OTOH, is able to capture `key = value` in `===key = value===`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: now mine is able to capture `key ==== value` `key = value`